# VMDK disk became read only & how to avoid such this cases on rhel machines

Tags: vmware-esxi, redhat, hard-drive, vmware-vsphere, mount

we have Kafka cluster with RHEL 7.6 , all Kafka are VM machines

on one of the Kafka machines , we noticed that sdb disk became read only ( when sda is the OS disk )

```
 mount | grep sdb
/dev/sdb on /var/data/kafka_DB type ext4 (ro,noatime,data=ordered)
```

from my point of view its little strange that DISK VMDK became read only ( because its not mechanic disk )

from red-hat I find the following

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1273213

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/35329

but not sure if above suggestions from redhat are the answer why disk became read only

any others opinions?

from the kernel logs we can see:

```
[1642397.157193] sd 0:0:2:0: [sdb] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_TIMEOUT
[1642397.157200] sd 0:0:2:0: [sdb] CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 12 c0 01 00 00 00 08 00
[1642397.157214] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 314573056
[1642397.157242] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 39321632, lost async page write
[1642397.157806] sd 0:0:2:0: [sdb] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_TIMEOUT
[1642397.157808] sd 0:0:2:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10) 28 00 12 c4 03 58 00 00 08 00
[1642397.157810] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 314835800
[1642397.157843] sd 0:0:2:0: [sdb] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_TIMEOUT
[1642397.157845] sd 0:0:2:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10) 28 00 12 c4 0b a0 00 00 08 00
[1642397.157847] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 314837920
[1642578.412306] sd 0:0:2:0: [sdb] task abort on host 0, ffff8c147c189880
[1642924.513605] sd 0:0:2:0: [sdb] task abort on host 0, ffff8c16a4f01880
[1643034.935334] JBD2: Detected IO errors while flushing file data on sdb-8
[1643035.002651] EXT4-fs error (device sdb): __ext4_new_inode:989: comm pool-6-thread-1: failed to insert inode 8126474: doubly allocated?
[1643036.753397] Aborting journal on device sdb-8.
[1643036.754490] EXT4-fs error (device sdb): ext4_journal_check_start:56: Detected aborted journal
[1643036.754496] EXT4-fs (sdb): Remounting filesystem read-only
[1643226.599854] sd 0:0:2:0: [sdb] task abort on host 0, ffff8c14a4bd3800
[1694249.598258] EXT4-fs (sdb): error count since last fsck: 17
[1694249.598269] EXT4-fs (sdb): initial error at time 1629844995: ext4_find_entry:1312: inode 656236
[1694249.598273] EXT4-fs (sdb): last error at time 1630003886: ext4_journal_check_start:56
[1780756.527074] EXT4-fs (sdb): error count since last fsck: 17
[1780756.527086] EXT4-fs (sdb): initial error at time 1629844995: ext4_find_entry:1312: inode 656236
[1780756.527088] EXT4-fs (sdb): last error at time 1630003886: ext4_journal_check_start:56
```

what we think to do , is to update the `/sys/block/`basename /dev/sdb`/device/timeout`

for example the default value is 180

and we are thinking to set update new value as

```
echo 3600 > /sys/block/`basename /dev/sda`/device/timeout
```

we want to know if we are on the right direction with above solution ?

Comment: Have you checked your kernel logs?

Comment: I update the question

Comment: What was the physical disk load at the time? Do you use a backup tool like Veeam? Is the physical disk exposed via the network to ESXi?

Comment: we not have access to the physical disk , so I can capture this info , what I want to know if redhat suggestion can help us?

Comment: we involved the ESX admin and he said that he not see any issues from the physical disk on data store